# getSVGDocument() returns null in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, safari

I am having a bit of a problem when trying to debug a webpage in Safari. In my mainpage I've got a iframe which I reload every three seconds to update tags on my mainpage. However, when I try using it in Safari, the following row is null

```
parent.document.getElementById(tagId).getSVGDocument();
```

I use this in order to update the fill of SVG objects on my main page. It seems as if the page stops the javascript after this line since it does not continue with the other functions I have on my mainpage.

Does anyone know what might be the problem with getSVGDocument() in Safari? Everything works as it should in IE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By looking into it further, it seems as if it is only IE which is able to find the svgDocument, I've got the same problem in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Tried adding an eventListener for the <object> through


var loaded = parent.document.getElementById(tagId);
loaded.addEventListener('load', function () {
 //code
}

but it seems to just skip the listener add move on to the next part.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed the problem by creating inline SVG's instead. Never got it to work with the  tags, but this was a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

`getSVGDocument` is not used anymore and there might be no support for newest versions of SVG.

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Scripting#inter-document_scripting:_referencing_embedded_svg):

> The best way to get access to the `Document` representing an SVG document is to look at `HTMLIFrameElement.contentDocument` (if the document is presented in an ) or `HTMLObjectElement.contentDocument` (if the document is presented in an  element)